# Adding a day to a Calendar in Android fails on 31st

Tags: java, android, calendar

Assume currently the date is the 28th of May. If I call the following commands in order the output becomes

```
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // Day = 29
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // Day = 30
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // Day = 31
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  // Day = 31
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -1); // Day = 29
```

Why is this not jumping into the next month? And why is it stuck at the 31st (but when you minus one it jumps to 29)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When you add 1 to the `Calendar.DATE` field, it should increment the month as well when the end of the month is reached (31 in the case for May) so that you wrote doesn't make sense.
Debug it and make sure the day value is indeed what you think it is

Answer (score 36):

You can easily do this in two simple ways my friend. First one is:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
```

and the second one is:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); 
cal.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 24);
```

I think you would like to find this thing.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

This should also do the trick.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
```

You can test it works with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Seems i'm wrong! acording to the api, roll only updates the spezific field!**

if you add days to a Calendar try

```
cal.roll(Calendar.DATE, 1);
```

this will increment month and year when overflown

Comment: roll only "rolls" the field you're changing and doesn't change the larger fields

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#roll(int, int)

Comment: @IncrediApp seems youre right, the explanation on roll suggests to the other direction in first place _"Increment or decrement the specified field and wrap the value of the field when it goes beyond the maximum or minimum value for the current date. Other fields will be adjusted as required to maintain a consistent date."_

Comment: As mentioned in below answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37291067/2641380 --- cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 50) works to get date after 50 days instead of using roll.

Answer (score 0):

I checked, it adds successfully. Look my code and o/p:

```
Calendar  cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // today is 09-Aug-2012

for(int i=0;i<23;i++) {
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);  
}
System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

O/p

`1`

Answer (score 0):

It is not an answer, just a clue: I found it happens when DST starts between dates. Maybe it's your case...

For example: Brazillian DST started this year at "Sun Oct 20 00:00:00 2013"

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(); // today = Sat Oct 19 00:00:00 BRT 2013
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 1); // = Sat Oct 19 23:00:00 BRT 2013
```

Unfortunately, I still don't know how to workaround that.